# Interpret google form summery responses

Tags: google-forms

I have taken a survey using Google forms where 3 people participated and now I can see graphs in my responses. The immediate interpretation is obvious, however I have some fundamental doubts about it. I was unable to find reasonable explanation online. See following question and its response:

[image]

[image]

It is clear from the response that 3 people participated and 2 of them opted for 2 and one opted for 1. my questions is:

What do X and Y axis represent, how they are divided into respective scale/intervals? Especially Y axis as for other questions, although the range of possible answers was same, the result looks different, see following image where scale of Y axis is changed:

[image]

Comment: Well, it changed, because 3 ppl answered option 1... the X axis is the answer to the question and Y is number of people, where maximum is the number of people at the highest scoring answer.

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply! I am just confused because in general the scale you use on axis remains same throughout your graphs, in the first it is 0.0 to 2.0 and and second it is 0 to 3. I understood that Y axis represents how many users chose respective answer but the scale differs making it hard for me to generalize in my text

Comment: Ah, I see. In figure no.1 it is decimal scale and in figure no.2 integer. Hm... hard to answer that... google misteries. Perhaps also because percentage has decimal?

Comment: Also why I am confused is, if say 2 people chose answer 2 making it the highest score, then why the scale should be 0.0-0.5-1.0-1.5-2.0 and not 0-1-2. Why they chose to divide Y axis into 4 intervals? I did not find reasonable explanation to it. As you can see, in second graph they have broken down Y axis into just 3 intervals!